# Add synonyms for the [stackoverflow] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are three tags for the concept of a "stack overflow" (not a certain website).  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) should be the main tag, while [stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) and [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) should be synonyms for it.

The "exception" tag seems to be common with C#/.NET questions, and the "error" tag seems to be targeted at Java specifically.  However, they are all the *exact same concept* and should be tagged with a specific language tag in those cases anyway.

I would do this myself, but I don't have the required 5 score in the tags to submit the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure I parse this sentence correctly: "However, they are all the exact same concept and should be tagged with a language-specific tag in those cases anyway." I think you miss a *not* somewhere in there.

Comment: @ArtjomB. [tag:stackoverflowerror] should be replaced with [tag:stackoverflow] and [tag:Java].

Comment: @Degustaf [really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror+-java+-android)  Those do not seem to be universally [tag:java].  Many are, but not all.

Comment: @Yakk I based that off of the OP's description, and meant it as an example.  The language specific tag should be the language, not the variant of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Yakk: Not all [stackoverflowerror] questions are about Java, but almost all seem to be JVM languages (Java, Scala, Groovy, Clojure) or JVM-based tools (Maven).  There's also a Javascript question and a C++ question which should just be tagged [stackoverflow].

Comment: My point was that the [stackoverflow*] tags should not be an indicator of language.  If a question is about a stack overflow in a specific language, it should be tagged with that language, not with a specific [stackoverflow*] tag.

Comment: Replacing "language-specific tag" with "specific language tag" removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Should access-violation and segmentation-fault also be merged? (this has a similar split, in this case on windows or unix topics)