# Synonymize [stackoverflowexception] and [stackoverflowerror] to [stackoverflow]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The [stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) states in its tag wiki that it is specifically for the .NET `stackoverflowexception`. But it is being used for Java, C#, C++, F# and ASP.NET questions. It is doubly confusing because I know that Java defines a `StackOverflowError` and I'm sure that C# and C++ do as well.

It seems to be a bit of a redundant tag when [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) itself has more questions and is more broadly applicable to questions. Having a specific tag for one language's flavor of stack overflow exception seems a little redundant<sup>1</sup>

This is my interpretation, do people concur? I'm suggest retagging questions with the more generic [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and then add [stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) and [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) as a tag synonym for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)

I realise that a duplicate question for this exists, however that question failed to actually change anything, because no one on meta seems to have both the required rep and the number of answers in these tags to suggest a tag synonym. Perhaps a mod could step in and help us?

<sub>1. "this is my treehouse for all my .NET friends and all you smelly Java geeks can just keep out"</sub>

Comment: +1,  but being picky Java actually defines a `StackOverflowError` ;)

Comment: It seems unecessary to have  a tag for this at all. The website is called StackOverflow, for Goodness' sake! :-)

Comment: A synonym-request might be better since there are a lot of people who can propose and vote on it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/topusers

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277447/14379

Comment: Well, what do you know, it is. Perhaps we can get some traction this time and actually have the request actioned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a request for a synonym to be created from [stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow), which makes sense. Most error types only have one tag, even when used across languages.

Stack Overflow has a synonym system which works well, you can learn about it at the ["Create tag synonym"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) help page. Basically, someone needs to suggest the synonym at [the tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/synonyms) and you need five others to agree with you and also vote there. Since I don't have enough rep in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)/[stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception), I can't do that.

As [mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287662/synonymise-stackoverflowexception-to-stackoverflow/287705#comment163172_287662), the same should be done for [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror).

Comment: Me either, that's why I put the question on meta.

Comment: Apparently the system doesn't work that well when many people with common sense agree over a synonym but none of them can vote.

Comment: I've taken [the suggested workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128874/183280) and tagged a few [questions I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+[stackoverflow]) with [tag:stackoverflow], so that right now I could suggest the synonyms.

Comment: FYI all, these tags have been synonymized to [stack-overflow] (note the dash).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this seems like a good idea. I’ve also taken the liberty of adding a hyphen, since there is no such thing as a stackoverflow.